how to filter mails on to with maxResults in the query param of gmail api?
So for a week i had this problem that i couldnt filter my list of messages based on 'to' prameter.
today i was testing on gmail api documentation website and checking the query that is being sent and i saw something weird.
when i dont send maxResult query param, my filter works fine
here is my q parameter :

and this is my response which is correct:

but when i add maxResult

my response turns into the last 200 mails from my account.

i dont know why this happens. i dont have any answers. can someone please help me with this?
my tests are done here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list?
